# Как запустить сервер?

Tags: php, сервер, zend-framework

Объясните, пожалуйста, начинающему:) 
Есть серверное приложение (все исходники), написанное на php zendframework. Есть свой домен и хостинг с доступом к нему по фтп. Что мне нужно залить на сервер и как запустить серверное приложение, чтоб оно заработало?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приложение - приложению рознь! На такой вопрос можно только ответить следующее: Нужно сделать некоторые действия. А так ответ @koko пока исчерпывающий.

Answer (score 1):

Если последняя версия фреймворка до 1.11 то там будет папка public. По стандарту на хостингах корневой каталог /var/www - то есть, public_html. А у вас приложение работает с папки public. Что бы решить эту проблему нужно или сменить корневой каталог или переместить все файлы с папки public в корень и изменить пути в application.ini и index.php на соответствующие.

Answer (score 0):

Файлы залейте на хост. Если, конечно, хост поддерживает эту библиотеку и PHP.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

В исходниках много разных папок и файлов (в том числе там и библиотеки). Просто все что есть залить, и все? Верно?

Comment: aгa))так и сделой,,

Comment: О какой библиотеке речь? Фреймворк - это не библиотека!